# No, an Adorner DOES NOT automagically take the DataContext of its AdornedElement in WPF

Tags: wpf, datacontext, adorner, adornerlayer

Original question: Does an `Adorner` automagically inherit the "DataContext" of its "AdornedElement" in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proves (or can prove) that it doesn't:

```
public class SomeObject
{ }

public class SomeAdorner : Adorner
{
    public SomeAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) : base(adornedElement)
    {
        // comment out the following statement to see that, by default, an adorner does not
        // take on the data context of its adorned ui element
        SetBinding(
            DataContextProperty,
            new Binding(DataContextProperty.Name)
            {
                Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
                Source = adornedElement
            }
        );
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);

        if ((e.Property.Name.Equals(DataContextProperty.Name)) && (e.NewValue is SomeObject))
        { MessageBox.Show("DataContext changed!"); }
    }
}

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Window1_Loaded);
    }

    void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(WindowContentWithElementName)
            .Add(new SomeAdorner(WindowContentWithElementName));

        WindowContentWithElementName.DataContext = new SomeObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning, the Adorner inherits the DataContext of the AdornerDecorator being used. So if you define an AdornerDecorator inside of another FrameworkElement, any adorners which you display will have the same DataContext of the FrameworkElement.